# pandas how to outer join without creating new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes like this:

```
date      value
20100101  100
20100102  150

date      value
20100102  150.01
20100103  180
```

The expected output should be:

```
date      value
20100101  100
20100102  150
20100103  180
```

The 2nd dataframe always contains newest value that I'd like to add into the 1st dataframe. However, the `value` on the same day may differ slightly between the two dataframes. I would like to ignore the same dates and focus on adding the new date and value into the 1st dataframe.

I've tried `outer join` in pandas, but it gives me two columns `value_x` and `value_y` because the value are not essentially the same on same dates. Any solution to this?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I've added the expected output, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates('date', keep='last')
print (df)
       date   value
0  20100101  100.00
0  20100102  150.01
1  20100103  180.00
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates('date', keep='first')
print (df)
       date  value
0  20100101  100.0
1  20100102  150.0
1  20100103  180.0
```

Comment: what if I want to keep the value from df1 when dates are the same?